# Unexplained extra entry in array

Tags: matlab

In a tutorial I was running today, the following problem came up a few times.

The code was something like this

```
x = [ x0 + v*cosd(theta) * t, y0 + v*sind(theta) * t + .5 *g * t^2]
```

However, when you output x, it had 3 entries with a zero before the two calculated values.  I have no idea how that happened.  I restyled the same code exactly and this problem disappeared.  Could this be some sort of bug with MATLAB?

Comment: It's probably not a bug in MATLAB. I think that code could return an array with 3 elements under some circumstances (e.g. if x0 was an array with two elements). Alternatively, you can specify arrays using spaces instead of commas. If you left out an operator you might have ended up with 3 elements (like [x0 v*cosd(theta)*t,y0...]) would treat x0 as an extra element. To know exactly what happened, I'd need to know a) what 'restyling' did you do? b) what were the values of x0,v,theta,t,y0,g?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matlab if you combine a vector with a scalar the resulting value is a vector. For example:

```
a = 1;
b = [1, 2];
c = a+b; % returns [2, 3];
```

So lets break down your equation:

```
 x = [ x0 + v*cosd(theta) * t, y0 + v*sind(theta) * t + .5 *g * t^2]
```

into:

```
A = x0 + v*cosd(theta) * t;
B = y0 + v*sind(theta) * t + .5 *g * t^2;
x = [ A, B];
```

`A` and `B` must both be scalars for `x` to be `1x2`. Your result is 1x3 because one of your variables because either `A` or `B` is 1x2.  This is the result of `x0`, `v`, `theta`, `t`, `y0`, or `g` not being a scalar but a `1x2` vector.

My suspicion is that `g`, `x0`, or `y0`, is the culprit as these variables are unique to a single equation. So I'd start by checking the size of these values. However without knowing the values of your variables I can't be sure.